# Get single list of inherited objects with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have a base class `Posts` and `Notifications`, `Notes` and `Photos` inherit from `Posts`. How can I a single list with all inherited objects from Posts in a single `List<Post>`.

```
            var notes = posts.OfType<Note>();
            var photos = posts.OfType<Photo>();
            var notifications = posts.OfType<Notification>(); ;

            return (from n in notes
                    select new Stream()
                    {
                        id = n.post_id,
                        value = n.value,
                        timestamp = n.timestamp,
                        type = "note"
                    }).ToList();
```

The above of course returns notes only.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you already have posts collection why are you using notes instead of it in linq query?

Comment: posts isn't returning the inherited objects...

Comment: Please include an example of what `posts` contains and what you would like to get out of it.

Comment: See my answer. You just need to add `notes`, `photos` and `notifications` into a `List<Posts>`

Answer (score 0):

You already have a list of objects that inherit from `Posts`:

```
var notes = posts.OfType<Note>();
var photos = posts.OfType<Photo>();
var notifications = posts.OfType<Notification>();
```

Make a list of `Posts` as follows.

```
List<Posts> posts = new List<Posts>();
```

and add `Posts`

```
//posts.Add(new Note());
//posts.Add(new Notification());
//posts.Add(new Photo());

posts.AddRange(notes);
posts.AddRange(photos);
posts.AddRange(notifications);

// do the projection into Stream
return (from n in posts
        select new Stream()
        {
            id = n.post_id,
            value = n.value,
            timestamp = n.timestamp,
            type = "note"
        }).ToList();
```